# ImportError: No module named cloud at App Engine App

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-vision

I try to deploy my python script at app engine but face with an error: "ImportError: No module named cloud".

I did everything like in [Installing a third-party library manual](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library). But it doe not work :(

So, what I have:

1) app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

2) appengine_config.py

```
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

3) requirements.txt

```
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3
google-cloud-vision==0.27.0
google-gax==0.15.15
google-resumable-media==0.3.1
google-api-python-client==1.6.4
google-auth==1.1.1
```

4) lib folders with all libs from

```
Used command:
pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt
```

5) main.py that use google cloud vision lib.

```
from google.cloud import vision # Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud.vision import types # Imports the Google Cloud client library
import os

def detect_labels_uri(uri):

# Setup Credentials
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'my_servive_acc_key.json'

def detect_labels_uri(uri):
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    image = types.Image()
    image.source.image_uri = uri

    response = client.label_detection(image=image)
    labels = response.label_annotations
    print('Labels:')

    for label in labels:
        print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
        print ''
        print(label.description)

try:
    detect_labels_uri('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gqYlS_r8I-Y/maxresdefault.jpg')
except:
    print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
    print ''
    print 'Oops! That was no valid URL. Try again...'
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/cgi.py:122)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/h~test-184307/20171029t190420.405148744830706371/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.cloud import vision # Imports the Google Cloud client library
ImportError: No module named cloud
```

Could you help me to understand where I was wrong?

Comment: Python modules are usually distributed via PyPI. There is a [cloud](https://pypi.org/project/cloud/) package there--not sure whether it is relevant.

Comment: Did you used same python when you install requirement and when you ran the app?

Comment: Yes, sure. I use python 2.7

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace and, if possible, your script code?

Comment: Yes, sure. I have added it to description.

Comment: Were your requirements actually installed? Do you have a `google/cloud` dir under your `lib` dir? I tried installing just `google-cloud-vision==0.27.0` but in my case it failed due to some build packages missing on my system and the lib dir was actually empty afterwards.

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't reference the `main.py` file in app.yaml, you should reference a variable representing a WSGI application defined in `main.py`, typically called `app`, like this: `script: main.app`. See script row in the [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) table. Probably not related to the import error, tho.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue 8 months later. I thought being on App Engine would make it easier to use Vision....